# Stripe Payment Intent : can we hold the payment Amount for some time. If yes then how much time?

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose any user payment to the provider for any service. then we have to holds(pause) the payment. When provider serves the user for their service then the provider collect the payment which is holds. If provider not serve the service then user collect its own payment which is pay to provider.

Comment: You can construct the payment as a **Subscription** with a single (Off-session ) payment and once the customer has given the card details they are saved for you to debit at a later time, or to ignore if the customer no longer requires the service.

Comment: Define "holding"? What sort of time scale are you expecting with this? Weeks? Days? hours? Months? Who is the "provider" ie is it you or an intermediary? Please  **edit** and clarify your question. Thank you.

Comment: max 1 week time

Comment: Please **EDIT** and update your question with the relevant information. Thank you.

Comment: holding means that we have to wait provider receive payment when service is done of the user

Answer (score 1):

For this context, you normally use what's referred to as **Authorize and Capture**, which works by default for max. 7 days; see [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later) and [this](https://support.stripe.com/questions/using-authorization-and-capture-with-paymentintents) for probably all the information you need.

If the clients are making payments of a variable amount on a recurring basis; I recommend you to [store their payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) for off-session usage at a first step, create a payment authorization when they book the service, by [using the manual capture mode](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-capture_method), and [capture the payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture) after the service has been provided.

Note that authorization and capture does not work for all payment methods (they have a [list of payment methods that support it](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/integration-options#additional-api-supportability). So make sure that the payment method which you store is compatible with **Authorize and Capture** for this to work.

According to this list, your payment methods should all support the `SetupIntent API` (to store the payment method), obviously the `PaymentIntents API`, `Manual Capture` (to authorize and capture), and eventually also `Setup Future Usage` (for recurring payments).

Finally, if you have an Admin Account at Stripe, note that they have a free Discord Channel where you can directly ask their developers for support. Technical Questions related to their API & related implementations are probably best made over there.